# VBScript IF statement to determine OS version and ServicePack

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I'm in the process of writing a deployment script for Office 2010 and several other applications, one of the issues we ran into in testing were some computers still had XP SP2, so I wanted to code in a a safety measure for this.

I came up with this

```
Set colOperatingSystem = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystem
ServicePack = objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion
Next

IF not ServicePack = "3" Then

MsgBox "WARNING: prerequisite to installing Microsoft Office 2010 Professional you must first install service pack 3" & VbCrlf & "your current Service Pack Version is " & ServicePack

ELSE

'Do Nothing

END IF
```

I plugged it into an XP SP2 machine and got the warning popup On_WindowLoad, so I was pleased, but then as soon as I plugged it into my windows 7 machine it throws the same message, digging into powershell a bit I realize that since windows 7 reports it's ServicePackMajorVersion number as "1" so it doesn't meet the conditional,

Hoping someone might have an idea how to write an IF / Conditional statement to bypass the Windows 7 PC's, I looked at build number which is 7601, but not sure how I would nest these

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To test if you are running under Windows XP you must check if the `Version` property of the `Win32_OperatingSystem` WMI class start with `5.1`

Check this sample

```
strComputer = "."
 Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")        
Set colOperatingSystem = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystem
ServicePack = objOperatingSystem.ServicePackMajorVersion
Version = objOperatingSystem.Version

Next

IF Mid(Version,1,3)="5.1" And  not ServicePack = "3" Then

MsgBox "WARNING: prerequisite to installing Microsoft Office 2010 Professional you must first install service pack 3" & VbCrlf & "your current Service Pack Version is " & ServicePack

ELSE

'Do Nothing

END IF
```

Comment: The perfectionist in me really wants to change the code to test for a service pack *less than 3*, but I realize that's probably in vein, as there won't be a SP4.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1249039

Look for the OS version first then if XP look for SP 3, if Win 7 look for SP 1.